# Text got scrambled on Tinyscreen+

Tags: display

Yesterday when I was trying to reset my [Tinyscreen+](https://tinycircuits.com/products/tinyscreenplus) by using a needle to flick its power switch (because the case made it hard to do it with my fingers). It was a bit clumsy and I may had shorted some connections in the process. After that, the text on the bottom part of the screen become scrambled as shown in the attached image.

Does anyone have an idea on what caused that and if it's fixable?

Thanks for any help

[image: screen picture]

Comment: you already said what caused it ... yes, it is probably fixable ... you have to determine where the failure is located ... you also have to decide if you want to spend time and money to repair it ... it is cheaper to replace it

Comment: If it still happens after you completely power off and back on you've probably destroyed the hardware. Time for a new screen and a $40 lesson learned the hard way.

Comment: You may be able to replace the OLED module itself if you're handy with a soldering iron. The controller is SSD1331, one likely part number for the display module is CFAL9664B-F-B2. Or, it looks like you're using monochrome images; you could replace with a much cheaper SSD1306-based display.

Comment: The schematic says it's a UG-9664HDDAG01 (not sure if it's just the controller or the whole thing). Although I think I'll just use the top 3/4 of the screen for now.